# Adapting Saag recipes to other greens

Tags: greens

My question really draws on the title of this corner of StackExchange, as I need Seasoned Advice on seasoning!

Unbidden, my garden produced a variety of mustard-y or radish-y greens - robust leaves with "hairy" under sides and juicy stems. Their sheer abundance overwhelmed my ability to consume them as salads, but I found they worked very well in Saag preparations.

Before attempting it myself, I seek your advice as to whether perilla leaves (aka "Japanese basil" or Korean "kkaennip") could be prepared in a similar way. In particular, I wonder:

1. Would perilla's combination of subtle "basil-y" and "mint-y" flavors combine well with traditional "curry" spices, or is there a more appropriate combination of traditional Japanese or Korean spices?
2. Will the subtle flavors even survive cooking?

Comment: Did you try it? If so, what kind of results did you get?

Comment: No - instead, I wrapped a seasoned filling of ground beef in the leaves and pan-fried them. Uses up a lot of leaves in a hurry and they're very addictive!